AWS Elastic Beanstalk load balancer logs: Access Denied for bucket
I am trying to set up logging for the load balancer with an Elastic Beanstalk app, and am running into an issue where the setting won't save as I get "Access Denied for bucket". I thought I set up the bucket policy correctly, so I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried with and without a prefix.
Policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/<prefix>/AWSLogs/<account id in format ####-####-####>/*"
        }
    ]
}

Other bucket properties:

Encryption: Server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3)
Block all public access: on

